# Spring MVC application - URL gives No file found (404)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I created a Spring-MVC project.

**web.xml**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/soundmails</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="somepkg.controllers" />

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.gmr.web.multipart.GMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1048576" />
</bean>

<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <!-- property name="location">
        <value>/WEB-INF/social.properties</value>
    </property-->
</bean>
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

The controller has this code:
**ProjectController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/soundmails")
public class FileUploadController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String test() {
        System.out.println("Hai");
        return "Hai";
    }
}
```

I am using Google App Engine in my local machine to test this.  I am getting these in my log:

> [INFO] Oct 24, 2013 1:54:18 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
>   [INFO] WARNING: No file found for: /soundmails/test

I tried /soundmails/soundmails/test as well. That is also giving the same error.

I am using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE

Can someone help me figure out what I am missing - /soundmails/test is giving 404 error.

Edit

I am unable to enable DEBUG logs for this.  For some reason, it is not taking log level configured in `logging.properties`

But I observed something interesting:

1) If I map the request to empty string (`value = ""`)

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String test() {
    System.out.println("Hai");
    return "Hai";
}
```

Then, when I try to access 127.0.0.1/soundmails, it works fine (returns string "Hai").

2) When I have `value="/test"`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String test() {
    System.out.println("Hai");
    return "Hai";
}
```

and I try to access 127.0.0.1/soundmails/test, it is giving HTTP 404.  This is weird.

Comment: What does your DEBUG log tell you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to enable Debug level logging.  That is a separate issue that I am figuring out.  I have made some edits to the question with some more results of my investigations on this particular issue.

Comment: Ok, next question: what is the context path of your deployed app? And what is the full url you are using to try to access the page. (You can fake the domain name if you'd like.)

Comment: I wonder if some kind of URL rewrite is breaking your context. Is that the full web.XML?

Comment: I enabled logging and the error was in web.xml.  It turns out, we need to map `/soundmails/*` to DispatcherServlet instead of `/soundmails`.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken about your setup, but it looks like "test" would actually be at the url /soundmails/sounmails/test, not just /sountmails/test.  Because of the servlet name in the web xml and the controller annotation, I think this is how that works.  However, I might be remembering the setup of Spring wrong - if so let me know and I'll have another look.

Comment: That is what I thought before starting to work on this.  But, when I tested with an empty-string in method-level RequestMapping annotation: `@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)` (see my edit in the question), it seems to only work with /soundmails not with /soundmails/soundmails.  I am using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE